# Conectar dbeaver a base de datos remota corriendo en docker

Tags: mysql, docker, dbeaver

Tengo una aplicación next.js + prisma corriendo en un contenedor de docker. Todo funciona bien en local, se conecta a la base de datos sin problema y se puede trabajar sin problema.

Para probar que no fuese un problema de docker, he intentado crear la conexión en DBeaver y  he visto que tampoco puedo conectar desde ahí. Aquí una imagen de ejemplo con la configuración:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por SSH nos podemos conectar correctamente con DBeaver, pero no conseguimos conectar con la BBDD corriendo en el contenedor de docker.

Esta es la respuesta cada vez que intentamos conectar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La configuración de la imagen de docker en el servidor es la siguiente:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mariadb:
    image: "mariadb"
    ports:
      - "3306:3309"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: "mi user"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "mi bd"
      LC_ALL: "en_US.UTF-8"
      LANG: "en_US.UTF-8"
      LANGUAGE: "en_US.UTF-8"
    networks:
      - mired
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/ico/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    command: ["mysqld", "--log-bin", "--max-allowed-packet=500M"]
  db_admin:
    image: "phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - mired
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      PMA_HOST: "mariadb"
      LC_ALL: "en_US.UTF-8"
      LANG: "en_US.UTF-8"
      LANGUAGE: "en_US.UTF-8"
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: "1000M"
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        MIX_ENV: prod
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    ports:
      - "8051:8001"
    environment:
      LC_ALL: "en_US.UTF-8"
      LANG: "en_US.UTF-8"
      LANGUAGE: "en_US.UTF-8"
    user: "root"
    links:
      - mariadb
    networks:
      - mired

networks:
  mired:
    external: true
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Quizá lo que está faltando es configurar la db para aceptar conexiones remotas.

Answer (score 0):

Yo veo un error en el puerto, está mapeando los puertos:

```
    ports:
      - "3306:3309"
```

MySql está escuchando en el puerto 3306 y ud lo tiene como **3309** al crear la imagen de docker.

debería ser:

```
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Por otro lado, debe configurar DBeaver en con la ip 127.0.0.0 ya que localhost no funciona con esa imagen de docker.